# "Tag is too long" error overflows sidebar in Ask Question page

Tags: bug, design, sidebar

When someone who's either faffing about or is actually trying to tag their question enters too many characters into the tag box, it shows an error:  "The tag X is too long", and that error overflows the sidebar:

[image]

It needs an `overflow-wrap: break-word` so it looks like this:

[image]